# Prove two equations are equivalent

Tags: neural-network

I'm reading [Neural Networks and Deep Learning](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap1.html) and running into trouble with the math. One of the exercises says:

Write out $a'=\sigma (wa + b)$ in component form, and verify that it gives the same result as the rule
$$\frac{1}{1 + \exp(-\sum_{j}w_jx_j - b)}$$for computing the output of a sigmoid neuron.

Not even sure where to start here. Can anyone help me out? I'd really appreciate a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your first equation **w** is weight matrix $(w_1 + w_2 + \ldots + w_j)$ and **a** is the input vector $(x_1 + x_2 + \ldots + x_j)$. Writing **wa** in component form means taking the dot product of these two vectors, which is $\sum_{j}w_ja_j$. Now, you just apply the sigmoid function to get your final answer:$$\sigma (z) = \frac{1}{1 + \exp(-z)}$$ $$\Rightarrow\sigma (\textbf{wa} + b) = \frac{1}{1 + \exp(-\sum_{j}w_jx_j - b)}$$